# Client and Server unable to exchange data python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using python 3.3.this is Server.py.Everything is fine both server and client are able to connect
something might be wrong in here 'tcpcli.send('[%s]%s'%(bytes(ctime(),'utf-8'),data))'.help me out

```
from socket import *
from time import ctime

HOST=''
PORT=21567
BUFSIZ=1024
ADDR=(HOST,PORT)

tcp=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
tcp.bind(ADDR)
tcp.listen(5)

while True:
    print('waiting for connection')
    tcpcli,addr=tcp.accept()
    print('...connected from:',addr)

    while True:
        data=tcpcli.recv(BUFSIZ)
        if not data:
            break
        tcpcli.send('[%s]%s'%(bytes(ctime(),'utf-8'),data))
    tcpcli.close()
tcp.close()
```

This is CLient.py

```
    from socket import *


HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=21567
BUFSIZ=1024
ADDR=(HOST,PORT)

tcpcli=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
tcpcli.connect(ADDR)


while True:
    data=input('>')
    if not data:
        break
    tcpcli.send(data)
    data=tcpcli.recv(BUFSIZ)
    if not data:
        break
    print (data.decode('utf-8'))

tcpcli.close()
```

When i'm running both they are working fine except I'm unable to send any data from client.
I'm getting this error message.

```
tcpcli.send(data)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building unicode strings, not byte strings, and the socket interface doesn't support unicode strings. You'll need to encode the *result* of the string interpolation:

```
    tcpcli.send(bytes('[%s]%s' % (ctime(),data), 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: @Martin hey thanks...it worked
i'm getting an extra b in output along with timestamp..ny help?

Answer (score 2):

You are using Python3. This means that, when using the CLI, `input()` will return a `str` object (equivalent to python2 `unicode`). It contains an internal representation of the unicode codepoints of the characters you entered. To send the data over a byte stream interface (such as pipes, sockets, …), you have to convert it to a bytes object. This is easily done by picking an encoding, such as UTF-8, and doing something like this:

```
data_raw = data.encode("utf-8")
tcpcli.send(data_raw)
```

You will have to adapt your servers code similarily, by first decoding the data you received from the client and reencoding it after you did string operations on it:

```
        data_decoded = data.decode("utf-8")
        reply = '[%s]%s' % (ctime(), data_decoded)
        tcpcli.send(reply.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: tcpcli.send(bytes('[%s]%s' % (ctime(),data), 'utf-8'))
is working great but i'm getting a 'b' extra in every output?ny idea